# PHP MySQL database file issue

Tags: php, mysql

This is my post edit page and it contains this code.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $target_dir = "images/post/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $title);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content);

    $date = latvian_date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', date='$date', thumbnail = '$target_file' where id=$pid";


    if($title =="" || $content ==""){
        echo "Please complete post!";
        return;
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

What do I have to change in this code? I don't want to update my `target_file` (post thumbnail) if I dont select any files in my form and update everything else. If there WAS file selected, i want to update it aswell. Hope you understand me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? And what exactly is the problem with what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into the query. Escaping variables is not sufficient to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 different UPDATE queries based upon whether there was a file uploaded, ive restructured your code a little to accommodate this.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    //
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? strip_tags($_POST['title']) : null;
    $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : null;
    $date = latvian_date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    if ($title == "" || $content == "") {
        echo "Please complete post!";
        exit;
    }

    // has upload
    if (file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
        $target_dir = "images/post/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        //$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "Failed upload!";
            exit;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE posts 
                SET title='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $title)."', 
                    content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content)."', 
                    date='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $date)."', 
                    thumbnail = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $target_file)."' 
                WHERE id=".(int) $pid;
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE posts 
                SET title='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $title)."', 
                    content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content)."', 
                    date='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $date)."'
                WHERE id=".(int) $pid;
    }

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    exit(header ("Location: index.php"));
}
```

Comment: np, your welcome, couple of pointers, check variables are set first (sanity), check variables are what you want (validate), handle your logic, return error out or continue.. and switch to using prepared queries, which will clean up them ugly queries. I dont normally answer mysqli_* questions as code always ends up ugly with the mysqli_real_escape_string calls. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 separate SQL statement by using an if condition if the file was not uploaded. You can check this by using the empty() function built into PHP. You also don't need to initiate your file(s) variables if no upload was submitted.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) 
{
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', date='$date', thumbnail = '$target_file' where id=$pid";
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', date='$date' where id=$pid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $target_dir = "images/post/";
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $title);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content);

    if($title =="" || $content ==""){
        echo "Please complete post!";
        return;
    }

    $date = latvian_date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', content='$content', date='$date'";
    // Check if there is a file uploaded
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])){
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $sql .= ", thumbnail = '$target_file'";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    }
    $sql .= "where id=$pid";

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

You check if there is an uploaded file, then add the part where you update to the query, this is not a perfect code as you need to consider when the upload fails you may want to re-write the way you handle file upload.